# Python won't find a string although it exists

Tags: python

I have a relatively simple script trying to parse a text file. I'm looking for the line with the text

> [new Agent/UDP]

in the text file, therefore I use:

```
for line in file_lines:
    if "[new Agent/UDP]" in line:
        print "found"
```

The problem is that it never finds the line even though it exists. On the same line the word "set" exists and it finds it, yet I need to identify a line after the string I mentioned before.

UPDATE:

Ok so the copy pasted code would be:

```
    for line in file_ns_lines:
        if source_name in line:
            if "[new Agent/UDP]" in line:
                print "found"
```

and here are a few lines from the file

```
set tg0sink0 [new Agent/Null]
set tg0src0 [new Agent/UDP]
set tg1sink0 [new Agent/TCPSink]
set tg1src0 [new Agent/TCP]
```

source_name will be tg0src0 in this case

Comment: tried here, it works. probably a typo

Comment: It might help to see a bit of the text file and the code that successfully finds something. Could help see what's different between what works and what doesn't

Comment: Maybe there is a mismatch in the encodings/special characters that makes python unable to recognise the pattern? Just an idea.

Comment: Building on what Cilyan said, I might try parts of `"[new Agent/UDP]"` until it breaks, that should tell you which part is problematic (eg try "new Agent", "new Agent/UDP", then add the brackets if those work)

Comment: After `for line in file_ns_lines:`, add `print repr(line)`.

Comment: The code that you posted works correctly; the problem may be related to the code you **didn't** post. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible self-contained program that demonstrates the error and copy-paste that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.